# Use PowerShell to delete windows user profiles except for admin account

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to write a script that I can assign to a task to be run weekly to delete inactive users.  At my previous jobs I did not get into a lot of scripting or PowerShell.  Right now I am having a hard time figuring out how to properly exclude a certain account from being deleted.  I am not sure if this is just because of utilizing `-whatif` so I can test this or if I am doing something wrong.

```
$AccountsToKeep = ('Domain\Account', 'Domain\Account')
Get-ADUser -filter "enabled -eq 'false'" -property WhenChanged -SearchBase "OU=Disabled, DC=Domain, DC=local" |
   where {$_.WhenChanged -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-30) -notin $AccountsToKeep } |
       Remove-ADuser -whatif |  
           Out-File C:\Temp\ADUC_Scripts\deletedusers.txt
```

Both the output file and what is generated by PowerShell is indicating that it will delete this admin account.

Comment: Is there any reason why you are doing this with a oneliner instead of using multiple lines? Oneliners add extra complexity to your scripts and in most cases (99,99% in my experience) its not needed.

Comment: I just typed from 1 screen to another and placed it in a long string not really thinking about it when I transferred it over.